# I can't connect to server and database with physical phone

Tags: android, spring, spring-boot, android-studio, retrofit

I'm programming a password manager app with Android studio and spring-boot as back-end and Mysql as the database.

My server is on localhost:8080 on my computer and my database is also on localhost:3306.

My app functions and communicate well when it's on the emulator of Android Studio. But when I try to connect to it with my physical smartphone (Samsung Galaxy A80), it can't connect and I can't understand why. It should work.

I tried to change the ip adress to the one I have on my phone in the retrofit of Android Studio. and change the port but it didn't work.

application.properties in spring-boot server

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/PasswordManager?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=SakeSaske77
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

This is the retrofit service setup on Android Studio

```
public class RetrofitService {

    private Retrofit retrofit;

    public RetrofitService() {
        initializeRetrofit();
    }

    private void initializeRetrofit() {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.185" +
                        ":8080")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson()))
                .build();
    }

    public Retrofit getRetrofit() {
        return retrofit;
    }

}
```

Comment: Which ip does your app use when running on emulator?

Comment: `the retrofit service setup on Android Studio` ? Is Android Studio serving anything? And your Android app?

Comment: Please only add an android-studio tag if you do not know how to handle the ide and have questions about it.

Answer (score 0):

because the `localhost` can be accessed directly only from the host which is your pc/laptop, your physical phone is connected to your machine, but not the `localhost`, you need a way to access the `localhost` of your machine from your phone, for this you need to use the `adb` commands, and specifically, you need to transfer the port of your machine to the phone with this command:

```
adb reverse tcp:8008 tcp:8080
```

Change `8080` with your `localhost` port.

if you're not installing the adb (& other SDK platform tools provided by the Android SDK), download it [from here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools)

Comment: I will try using your command. But I am trying to connect to the ip adress of my pc not localhost.
I also think I found the problem. I could connect to it when I was at school on the public wifi. I think there must be a firewall stoping me or something.